# Curl 35 error when try to install plugins

Tags: 22.04, ssl, curl

Im trying to install some plugins in **wordpress** on Ubuntu 22.04 vps but I get ssl errors for some plugins

```
Downloading installation package from https://roadthemes.com/plugins/mega_main_menu.zip…

Download failed. cURL error 35: error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error
```

I tried to install the zip manualy but same error:

```
root@ubuntu:/home# curl -O https://roadthemes.com/plugins/mega_main_menu.zip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) error:0A000438:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert internal error
```

The command dpkg -l openssl gives :

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version           Architecture Description
+++-==============-=================-============-====================================================
ii  openssl        3.0.2-0ubuntu1.10 amd64        Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - cryptographic utility
```